# How to do partial search on multiple keys dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I create a multiple keys dictionary as (registrantsFields is enumerable type)

```
var registrantsRepository = registrantsFields.ToDictionary(c => Tuple.Create(c.RegistrantID, c.FieldID, c.DataID));
```

I use ContainsKey to search the dictionary as

```
if (registrantsRepository.ContainsKey(Tuple.Create(registrantId, fieldId, dataId)))
```

So far it works fine.

But I want to search the dictionary with only 2 keys, i.e. what dictionary contains for certain registrantId and fieldId, but with any dataId. In other word, I like to find all items like

```
var entries = registrantsRepository(Tuple.Create(registrantId, fieldId, *))
```

How should it be done (perhaps in Linq)? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any performance requirements? Do you care if it takes O(n) or O(1) to find the value?

Comment: Yes, I need as quick as possible.

Comment: Do you need to add more items to the dictionary after you decide to search? Or can you consider the dictionary "closed"?

Comment: The dictionary can be considered to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just create a separate Lookup.

```
var registrantsByIdAndField = registrantsFields
    .ToLookup(r => Tuple.Create(c.RegistrantID, c.FieldID));
```

Then you still get fast lookups with this:

```
var entries = registrantsByIdAndField[Tuple.Create(registrantId, fieldId)];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no wildcard search like that, but there is a way to ignore those fields that you're not interested in when you're doing your search.

Iterate through the collection of [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx), referencing the properties of your `Tuple` that you're interested in matching on. You can do this using LINQ's `Any` method.

```
if (registrantsRepository.Keys.Any(x => x.Item1 == registrantId && x.Item2 == fieldId)
{

}
```

Comment: In this case, how to get actually data for registrantId and fieldId?

Answer (score 1):

All good answers here. Is `ToLookup` an option for you?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073(v=vs.100).aspx

Edit: just realized @StriplingWarrior beat me to this!